# Remove duplicate DOM element ( Javascript not jQuery)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a list contains some dublicate elements and I need to remove the dublication :

in this case i need to remove the two latest elements because they are the same as the first one:

```
<ul class="list"> 
        <li class="list-item" data-id="5">5</li> 
        <li class="list-item" data-id="4">4</li> 
        <li class="list-item" data-id="5">5</li> 
        <li class="list-item" data-id="5">5</li> 
</ul>
```

I need the result like this ( only the elements with the unique value ) :

```
<ul class="list"> 
        <li class="list-item" data-id="5">5</li> 
        <li class="list-item" data-id="4">4</li> 
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the easiest way is to loop over all the list elements while keeping track of all IDs seen so far, and remove any elements whose ID whose id you've already seen earlier:

```js
function removeDupes() {
  const seenIDs = {};
  for (const item of document.querySelectorAll('#mylist > .list-item')) {
      if (seenIDs[item.dataset.id]) item.parentNode.removeChild(item);
      else seenIDs[item.dataset.id] = true;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul class="list" id="mylist"> 
        <li class="list-item" data-id="5">5</li> 
        <li class="list-item" data-id="4">4</li> 
        <li class="list-item" data-id="5">5</li> 
        <li class="list-item" data-id="5">5</li> 
</ul>
<button onclick="removeDupes()">Remove duplicates</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Select the `li` elements and map the array to have the `id`, use `[...new Set()]` to remove the duplicates, then `map` the new deduped array to the original `html` element and set the `innerHTML` of `ul` to that :

```js
const lis = [...document.querySelectorAll('li')].map(li => li.dataset.id);
const elems = [...new Set(lis)];

document.querySelector('ul').innerHTML = elems.map(id => '<li class="list-item" data-id="' + id + '">' + id + '</li>').join('');
```

```html
<ul class="list">
  <li class="list-item" data-id="5">5</li>
  <li class="list-item" data-id="4">4</li>
  <li class="list-item" data-id="5">5</li>
  <li class="list-item" data-id="5">5</li>
</ul>
```